# Databricks spark job writing/updating _SUCCESS file twice on job completion

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, databricks

I'm using S3 event based triggers to trigger lambda functions. It triggers a lambda function every time an _SUCCESS file is written at a specific location in S3. Data is being written at the source location using Databricks spark jobs. It has been observed that once the job writes data to source location, the lambda function is trigger twice, consistently.

This behavior is only observed when _SUCCESS is written by Databricks job. I tried to write the file from CLI, it triggers the lambda function just once.

It would be helpful to know the reason behind such a behavior from Databricks jobs.

Comment: Did you get to know why that was happening ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue - s3 events to trigger lambdas based on the _SUCCESS file. Did you figure it out how to fix this?

Comment: @user3199285 please let me know if you figured that out too

Comment: I've asked this question again to see if someone answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585344/databricks-spark-job-writes-success-files-twice

Comment: Did you get the reason for this?