# Databricks Spark Job writes _SUCCESS files twice

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

For reference, I'm having the exact same issue reported here without answers: [Databricks spark job writing/updating _SUCCESS file twice on job completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258803/databricks-spark-job-writing-updating-success-file-twice-on-job-completion)

I have a lambda that is triggered by s3 events on the _SUCCESS file. When the dataframe is written via Databricks/Spark with `df.write.parquet(path)` the _SUCCESS file is written twice, as you can see from the s3 file versioning:

[image: S3 File Versoning]

This messes up with my lambda as I'm expecting just one _SUCCESS file (and as reported above, this happens only when using databricks.